# Disabled MenuItem is not greyed out on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I have a menu for templates in my app, and there is a menu item inside for removing the templates. When there are no existing templates, the menu item is disabled. I binded IsEndabled property to the Templates.Count and everything works perfectly on Windows 8 or 10, but on Windows 7 the item is not greyed out (but disabled).

My xaml for the "Remove templates..." menu item:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource RemoveTemps}" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding Templates.Count, 
          Converter={StaticResource intToBoolConverter}}" 
          Command="{Binding RemoveTemplatesCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Snippent from ViewModel class:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private StringCollection _templates = Properties.Settings.Default.Templates;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Templates { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindowViewodel()
    {
        foreach (string s in _templates)
        {
            Templates.Add(s);
        }
    }

}
```

If any info is missing in order to resolve the issue, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue.

Please try to add parameter

Is async to your binding:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Do it like this

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource RemoveTemps}" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding Templates.Count, 
          Converter={StaticResource intToBoolConverter}}" 
          Command="{Binding RemoveTemplatesCommand, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

It works for me.